# <a> tag to span multi-row flex items

Tags: html, flexbox, hyperlink

Is it possible for one `<a>` tag to span multiple flex items across two or more flex rows?

**Example 1:**

```
<div class="inline md:flex md:flex-row md:justify-between">
  <span>word 1</span>
  <span>word 2</span>
  <span>word 3</span>
</div>

<div class="inline md:flex md:flex-row md:justify-between">
  <span>word 4</span>
  <span>word 5</span>
  <span>word 6</span>
</div>
```

Tailwind Playground [link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/HKKXoYUlUi).

.. and somehow have one linkable `<a>` tag wrap across e.g. `word 1-4` or `word 2-6` ? This should by default work for both `inline` and `flex` layout, depending on breakpoint in media query.

Comment: This has nothing to do with tailwind or css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot close a parent tag (In your case the first `<div>`) without closing all child tags in it (in your case the `<a>` tag you want to insert), that would be invalid HTML.

If you try it nevertheless, the browser will try to correct it and close the child tags (i.e. the not-closed `<a>` tag) *before*  the closing `</div>`  tag, so no, that's not possible.

ADDITION AFTER COMMENTS:

A simple grid solution would be something like this:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.parent span {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent a {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>word 1</span>
  <a href="#">
    <span>word 2</span>
    <span>word 3</span>
    <span>word 4</span>
    <span>word 5</span>
    <span>word 6</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

This has an `a` tag around elements 2-6. Note the `display: contents;` setting for `.parent a`, which makes sure the `a` isn't treated as a grid item, but ignored concerning the grids parent/child relation.

BTW: You can google "css grid generator"  for tools to to generate the grid code according to given settings, which you then can modify, inserting the `a` tags and your contents.

Comment: Well, I assume then the best alternative is not to use `flex` at all, and just pure vanilla `inline`, however I then lose the display option of `justify-between` and need to settle with `text-justify`, even while it justify text differently. Is their an alternative way to get the desired results in pure HTML/CSS ?

Comment: You could use just *one*  parent div, still use flex and apply according width, padding or margin settings to the children to achieve three items per row. Or you use grid inside *one*  parent div.

Comment: Johannes can you elaborate on how this is to be accomplished with *one* parent flex/grid, I can't see how this solve the problem

Comment: I added some example code.

Answer (score -1):

Just create an outer div to wrap around your block of code. Wrap this complete block in an anchor tag

```
    <a href="#"><div class="
    container-fluid">
    <div class="inline md:flex 
    md:flex-row 
    md:justify-between">
    <span>word 1</span>
    <span>word 2</span>
    <span>word 3</span>
    </div>

    <div class="inline md:flex 
    md:flex-row 
    md:justify-between">
    <span>word 4</span>
    <span>word 5</span>
    <span>word 6</span>
    </div>
    </div></a>
```

Comment: This won't work as it's all or nothing, e.g. you can wrap one/more words from first `div` and one/more words from second `div`.